# Regex char class - more elegant solution

Tags: regex, syslog, traffic-filtering

I have two barracuda FWs with different log structure and a Logstash grok filter plugin that needs to parse them.

### values only log entry

```
+02:00 Info     blabla Detect: FWD|TCP|bond0.777|1.1.1.1|53329|00:00:00:00:00:00|20.190.159.32|443||bond1.182||0|80.231.71.252|20.190.159.32|0|1|0|0|0|0||SSL|Microsoft Services Base|graph.microsoft.com||Computing/Technology (82)
```

### fields + values log entry

```
+02:00 Info     blabla Remove: type=FWD|proto=UDP|srcIF=pvpn0|srcIP=1.1.1.1|srcPort=61661|srcMAC=00:00:00:00:00:00|dstIP=10.248.0.10|dstPort=53|dstService=dns|dstIF=pvpn0|rule=V2L-DNS-IN|info=Balanced Session Idle Timeout|srcNAT=10.248.11.215|dstNAT=127.0.0.1|duration=20|count=1|receivedBytes=444|sentBytes=82|receivedPackets=1|sentPackets=1|user=johba|protocol=|application=|target=|content=|urlcat=
```

I already have a regex for the first scenario. However, I'd like to have a single regex that would match in both cases, no matter if the filed names are present.

For instance I'd like my regex to match both `FWD` and `type=FWD`

1. I tried with char class first, i.e. `[type=]*\w+`. Con is that, for instance if I have `dstService=dns`, and the portion of my regex is `[dstService=]*\w+` the grok filter would match `ns` only instead of `dns`
2. Then I tried with `d*s*t*S*e*r*v*i*c*e*=*\w+` and this worked. However, I was thinking if there was more elegant way of achieving this goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A character class matches 1 character in the range defined in the class.

For example,

- `[type=]*\w+` matches 0 or more any character in the range `t`, `y`, `p`, `e`, or `=` followed by 1 or more word character (i.e. `[a-zA-Z0_9_]`)
- `[dstService=]*\w+` matches 0 or more any character in the range `d`, `s`, `t`, `S`, `e`, `r`, `v`, `i`, `c` or `=` followed by 1 or more word character (i.e. `[a-zA-Z0_9_]`)

What you want to match is :

- 1rst `(?:type=)?FWD`

  - matches optional `type=` followed by `FWD`
- 2nd `(?:dstService=)?dns`

  - matches optional `dstService=` followed by `dns`

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/PgEVfW/1)

Comment: Thank you bro, you're awesome :)

Comment: @lord_sommersby: You're welcome, glad it helps. Feel free to mark the answer as accepted, [How to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: Done and thanks again for the link :) cheers :)